# Uninstall QGis and related ports with Macports

Tags: uninstallation, qgis, macports, pyqgis

I want to uninstall QGIS3 and all installed depandances (Python etc) and ports. The installation was done with Macports (sudo ports install qgis3).
I have not found a listing of all the things installed in the process and would like to avoid uninstalling the previously installed x11.app.
The reason is that there were several messages with "failed" in the installation process. As in the following example:

```
   Error: Failed to build py311-mapclassify: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-mapclassify/py311-mapclassify/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there
is a bug.
Error: Processing of port qgis3 failed
```

I used first:

```
sudo port clean --all qgis3
```

and I ran afterwards:

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents qgis3
```

but without any result.

How can I do the uninstall process?

Infos about the installed qgis Version:

```
qgis3 @3.28.7_1 (gis)
Variants:             debug, grass, grass7, postgresql10, postgresql11,
                      postgresql12, postgresql13, postgresql14, [+]postgresql15,
                      postgresql95, postgresql96, proj6, proj7, proj8, [+]proj9,
                      [+]python310, python37, python38, python39, server,
                      universal

Description:          QGIS is a full-featured, user-friendly,
                      free-and-open-source (FOSS) geographical information
                      system (GIS) that runs on Unix platforms, Windows, and
                      MacOS.
Homepage:             https://www.qgis.org/

Build Dependencies:   cmake, pkgconfig, bison, ld64, flex, py310-pyqt-builder,
                      py310-sip
Library Dependencies: libiconv, expat, libtasn1, libzip, openssl, gsl, geos,
                      gdal, PDAL, protobuf3-cpp, exiv2, sqlite3, spatialite,
                      spatialindex, qca-qt5, qca-qt5-ossl, qtkeychain-qt5,
                      qwt-qt5, qjson-qt5, postgresql15, python310, py310-pyqt5,
                      py310-pyqt5-scintilla, py310-gdal, py310-six,
                      py310-protobuf3, proj9, qt5-qtbase, qt5-qtwebkit,
                      qt5-qtscript, qt5-sqlite-plugin, qt5-qtscxml,
                      qt5-qtxmlpatterns
Runtime Dependencies: py310-psycopg2, py310-requests, py310-owslib, py310-yaml,
                      py310-jinja2, py310-pygments
Platforms:            darwin
License:              GPL-2+
Maintainers:          Email: vince@macports.org, GitHub: Veence
                      Policy: openmaintainer
```